# Does FFIV Advance have an EEPROM save?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

Will the save file dissapear due to time ?  (I got the legit copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through this [GBAtemp thread](https://gbatemp.net/threads/gameboy-advance-gba-games-requiring-batteries.322803/), I get conflicting information. It states that some versions of FFIV have batteries (first releases) but some don't.

Somewhere [else](http://www.racketboy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17201) it says that only bootleg versions have batteries.

The only way to check is to open up the cartridge. If there is a battery, yes, your save files can dissapear.

Comment: Oh ok, maybe my version have an EEPROM...I don't know, and maybe isn't one of the first releases since i bought my game in the year 2007-2008...